# Sum item inside a tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, sum, tuples

I have a list of nested tuples in which the second element is na float:

```
l = [('drink', ['vodka', '9.2', 'beer', '6.3', 'alcohol', '5.4', 'gin', '2.1', 'liquid']), 
('evict', ['tenant', '66.0', 'squatter', '2.75', 'owner', '1.1', 'bum', '1.0', 'deadbeat', '1.0'])]
```

I want to sum the three first items on the list, and append the result to the beginning, like this:

```
l = [('drink', 20.9 ['vodka', '9.2', 'beer', '6.3', 'alcohol', '5.4', 'gin', '2.1']), 
('evict', 69.75 ['tenant', '66.0', 'squatter', '2.75', 'bum', '1.0', 'deadbeat', '1.0'])]
```

I am using the code below:

```
sorted_by_sum=[]
for t in l:
    tup=[t[0]]
    tup.append(t[1])
    tup.append(sum(float(x) for x in t[0][1:6:2]))
    sorted_by_sum.append(tuple(tup))
```

But I am getting the mistake:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'a'
```

Any hints on what how to correct this? I thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to access the *second* element of the tuple to sum; not `t[0]` (the string):

```
tup.append(sum(float(x) for x in t[1][1:6:2]))
```

but make that the first `.append()` statement, not the second.

You can turn the whole loop into a list comprehension, using tuple unpacking to give easier to follow names to the two elements of each tuple:

```
sorted_by_sum = [(name, sum(float(x) for x in items[1:6:2]), items) 
                 for name, items in l]
```

Demo:

```
>>> l = [('drink', ['vodka', '9.2', 'beer', '6.3', 'alcohol', '5.4', 'gin', '2.1', 'liquid']), 
... ('evict', ['tenant', '66.0', 'squatter', '2.75', 'owner', '1.1', 'bum', '1.0', 'deadbeat', '1.0'])]
>>> [(name, sum(float(x) for x in items[1:6:2]), items) for name, items in l]
[('drink', 20.9, ['vodka', '9.2', 'beer', '6.3', 'alcohol', '5.4', 'gin', '2.1', 'liquid']), ('evict', 69.85, ['tenant', '66.0', 'squatter', '2.75', 'owner', '1.1', 'bum', '1.0', 'deadbeat', '1.0'])]
```

Comment: I worked beautifully! Thank you so much! I'll accept as soon as possible!